# No "Cloud SQL" option in the Google Cloud Console

Tags: java, google-cloud-sql

I just created a simple servlet project using the Google Eclipse plugin, and was able to test it correctly. I now want DB access and am therefore trying to set up a cloud SQL instance. In order to do so, I understand that I have to enable billing, which I have done. But, the Cloud SQL option still does not show in the Cloud Console. It has been more than 12 hours now since billing was enabled. Does it take longer? Or am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks,
Ranjit

Comment: The solution that worked for me was to create the project from the Cloud Console and not from the Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry you have run into this issue.   I suspect you have an "App Engine Only" project.   The easiest fix is to go to http://appengine.google.com, find your project, select Application Settings then find Cloud Integration and click the button there.  Then go back to http://cloud.google.com/console, find your project and you should have a SQL option.